# PHPExcel skipping rows when writing to a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, phpexcel

I've got an HTML table which I display rows about users on the system. These rows are also written to an Excel Spreadsheet which is downloadable. Exactly the same information is sent to the spreadsheet:

```
  $row=2;
  $odd='';
  foreach($feedata as $user_data){
    $col=1;
    $name=$user_data['first_name'].' '.$user_data['surname'];
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $name);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row,$user_data['email']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $user_data['phone']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $user_data['regdate']);
    $odd=($odd=='even')?'odd':'even';
    echo '
    <tr  class="<?php echo $odd;?>">
      <td>
        <a href="'.$URI.'?userid='.$user_data['id'].'">
        '.$name.'
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#self" onclick="showmailform(\''.$name.'\',\''.$user_data['email'].'\');return false;">
        '.$user_data['email'].'
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        '.$user_data['phone'].'
      </td>
      <td>
        '.$user_data['regdate'].'
      </td>
      ';
    for($i=2015;$i<$subscriptions;$i++){
      $amnt=$user_data[$i];
      $sp_amnt='';
      if(!$amnt){
        $amnt='&nbsp;';
      }
      else{
        $sp_amnt=$amnt;
        if(is_numeric($amnt)){
          $amnt='&pound;'.$amnt;
        }
      }
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $sp_amnt);
      $cellname=chrono_char($col).$row;
      # $objPHPExcel-getStyle($cellname)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode($currencyFormat);
      echo '
        <td>'.$amnt.'
        </td>';
    }
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $user_data['paid_upto']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $user_data['paymentEA']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $user_data['paymentHWSA']);
    $row++;
    echo '
    <td>'.$user_data['paid_upto'].'</td>
    <td>'.$user_data['paymentEA'].'</td>
    <td>'.$user_data['paymentHWSA'].'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
  }
  echo '</table>';
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
  echo 'Download excel version of the report <a href="'.plugins_url('chrono_reg/tmp/').'subscriptions.xls">HERE.</a>';
  renderEmailForm();
  $excelfilename=$pldir.'tmp/subscriptions.xls';
  $objWriter->save($excelfilename);
  chmod($excelfilename, 0664);
  chown($excelfilename,'www-data');
```

The HTML table comes out correctly, but the spreadsheet is missing lines.

HTML Table:

```
Paula Ilott | Ptxxxxx@example.co.uk | 087xxxxxx | 04-04-2016 |   |   |   |   |   |   |  |  | 
---------------------------------------------------------------
Damian Jesson | dxxxx@gmail.co.uk | 01708 xxxx xxx | 23-05-2016 |   |   |   |   |   |   |  |  | 
---------------------------------------------------------------
Nicolette Middleton | nxxxxx@gmail.com | +44xxxxxxxxxxx | 11-02-2016 |   | £53.00 |   |   |   |   | 31-03-2016 | 31-03-2017 |
```

Spreadsheet Table:

```
Paula Ilott | Ptxxxxx@example.co.uk | 087xxxxxx | 04-04-2016 |   |   |   |   |   |   |  |  | 
---------------------------------------------------------------
Nicolette Middleton | nxxxxx@gmail.com | +44xxxxxxxxx | 11-02-2016 |   | 0 |   |   |   |   | 31-03-2016 | 31-03-2017 |
```

I'm completely baffled.

As a separate issue, the payment amount is always '0' in the spreadsheet (it's 53.00 in the example above), but I will research that once I have this discrepancy resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten the code and it seems to work now.

I'm honestly at a loss to see what was wrong.

The code posted above wasn't quite what I had as I did a bit of editing to make the question clearer. It was originally mostly in HTML with **< ?php echo $name;?>** instead of using **echo '< td>'.$name.'< /td>';** as I'd posted above.

Here's what the original code looked like:

```
$row=2;
$odd='';
foreach($feedata as $user_data){
  $col=1;
  $name=$user_data['first_name'].' '.$user_data['surname'];
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $name);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row,$user_data['email']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $user_data['phone']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $user_data['regdate']);
  $odd=($odd=='even')?'odd':'even';?>
  <tr  class="<?php echo $odd;?>">
    <td>
      <a href="<?php echo $URI.'?userid='.$user_data['id'];?>">
      <?php echo $name;?>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#self" onclick="showmailform('<?php echo $name."','".$user_data['email'];?>');return false;">
      <?php echo $user_data['email'];?>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $user_data['phone'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $user_data['regdate'];?>
    </td>
    <?php
  for($i=2015;$i<$subscriptions;$i++){
    $amnt=$user_data[$i];
    $sp_amnt='';
    if(!$amnt){
      $amnt='&nbsp;';
    }
    else{
      $sp_amnt=$amnt;
      if(is_numeric($amnt)){
        $amnt='&pound;'.$amnt;
      }
    }
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $sp_amnt);
    $cellname=chrono_char($col).$row;
    # $objPHPExcel-getStyle($cellname)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode($currencyFormat);
    echo '
      <td>'.$amnt.'
      </td>';
  }
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $user_data['paid_upto']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $user_data['paymentEA']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $user_data['paymentHWSA']);
  $row++;?>
  <td><?php echo $user_data['paid_upto'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $user_data['paymentEA'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $user_data['paymentHWSA'];?></td>
  </tr><?php
}
echo '</table>';
```

Sorry if I've wasted anyone's time on this; I really should have tested the revised code before posting it.